# How to generate Flatten PDF (read only) in Yii2 (PHP)?

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, flatten

I'm using karthik/mPDF to generate a PDF document with fields filled in. When the doc is saved, I'd like it to be read-only, aka flattened. I've tried but still, when opening the PDF in Adobe, the fields are editable.

Comment: 'I've tried the below'? What have you tried?

Comment: yes i also tired @Klaassiek

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: With MPDF you won't be able to do it. You should use an external CLI app like PDFtoCairo or PDFTK called from your code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882223/php-flatten-pdf-form-after-filling-fields-with-fpdm-without-pdftk