# Extract PDF form meta-data from PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, pdf-form

I want to fill government PDF forms using a web application. Here's one such example:

https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/g-28.pdf

Before I fill the form, I need to have form field names to map them with data source.

I tried pdftk to extract form field data but document is protected with owner password.

```
$ pdftk g-28.pdf dump_data_fields output g-28-metadata.txt

OWNER PASSWORD REQUIRED, but not given (or incorrect)
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Does anyone know how can I extract form fild data using any open-source or paid libraries?

Answer (score 0):

PDFTK does supports the password encryption and decryption while performing any action.  You need to use `input_pw` then your password in your command. Use the command as follows

```
pdftk input.pdf input_pw my_pass dump_data_fields output k.txt
```

If you are looking for how to fill the form programatically check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63047502/6051682).

Please comment if you have any issue.

Comment: I doubt the OP has access to passwords of government forms...

Comment: @mkl The question is not regarding how to get the password but how to use the password. The error on the screen says that the Owner password is required, so that is the problem.

Comment: *"The question is not regarding how to get the password but how to use the password."* - no, it's essentially how to get along without password. Why should a government agency publish their passwords?

Comment: @mkl why would he be filling out the forms whose passwords he does not have? He has the password plus the console has errors, so his problem his how would he extract the field data of a password protected form. Otherwise he is doing something unethical.

Comment: Because one strictly does not need the *owner* password to *fill in*, merely to structurally change forms. Pdftk here requires the owner password without need.

Comment: @mkl That is not true in every condition, so basically if a pdf just have user password set and you try any operation on it, pdftk will respond as owner password is required. I have this tested myself and the solution given by me will work for both user password and owner password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223600/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-mkl).

Comment: According to the pdftk documentation, "Most pdftk features require that encrypted input PDF are accompanied by the ~owner~ password." This most likely is the problem of the OP who wants merely to fill the form, something he doesn't need the owner password for when doing it in a PDF viewer.

Comment: @mkl to fill a pdf programmatically you need to know the name of the fields, so he is not trying to change the format but he wants to fill the form and get the names of the fields  which is quite clear from the question.

Comment: OK, so you concur.

Comment: My sincere apology for delayed response to this thread. I posted this question on Adobe Forum:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/autofilling-government-pdf-forms/m-p/11535354?page=1#M282822 

Looks like like I need access to LiveCycle Designer to be able to edit this form. Moreover, @mlk is correct on this one. I do not have password. My question was more around if I am doing something wrong to access the metadata - not about how to get around the password.